# Angular load external class inside service

Tags: angular, service

I am trying to load a external typescript class inside my angular service. I have a service called anyservice. And I am creating a export class inside one folder and I want to get one function inside my service for that my code for class is:

```
export class Functions {
testy() {
    alert("I am testy");
 }
 }
```

I am calling this Functions class inside my service using:

```
 import{Functions} from '../data/f'
```

But inside my service when I am trying to get this using:

```
 constructor(private f: Functions)
```

I am getting error:

```
 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Functions]:
```

StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Functions]:

How can I call my function inside my service like this:

```
 test() {
  this.f.testy();
 }
```

What is the best possible way to access external class inside services

Comment: are you missing @Injectable()?

Comment: if it is just a typescript class as you have it then you cannot inject it into the constructor but you can instantiate it: `const f = new Functions(); f.testy();`

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you can add the `Injectable` decorator to your class. However, if you can't (maybe it's a classs from a 3rd party library), you can still inject it in your components/services as long as you declare it in the module's providers

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [Functions]
})
```

**Note**: The `Injectable` decorator would be required on your `Functions` class if that class required some other class to be injected in its own constructor.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egxzxs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservice.ts)

Comment: The solution is not to add @Injectable decorator at the begining of the service.  `Functions` to be visible inside the service, probably `Functions` is missing inside `providers` at module file.